# Selenium webdriver get all the data attributes of an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium webdriver I have the following element

```
<div data-1223="some data" data-209329="some data" data-dog="some value">
```

Is there a way to get all the data- attributes of the element?
For a specific attribute I can use

```
elem.getAttribute('data-1223')
```

but how can I get all the data attributes together

Answer (score 17):

Use below Code:-

```
WebElement element = "Your Element"; // Your element
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Object aa=executor.executeScript("var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;", element);
System.out.println(aa.toString());
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Don't forget to check that your driver is a `JavascriptExecutor` before casting to it :) Several driver classes do not implement this.

Comment: @PaulHicks *Several driver classes do not implement this* Fair enough to do the check, though I can't think of any impls that don't implement this...? All 11 in my proj do.

Comment: Any driver that wraps SimpleBrowser doesn't, which is pretty obvious, since SimpleBrowser doesn't support JavaScript.  Also, the `EventFiringWebDriver` doesn't, though it does give you access to `WrappedDriver`, which almost always does.

Comment: Matter of interest: you shouldn't need 11 drivers. If you have to deal with that many browsers, consider delegating everything to `RemoteWebDriver` and letting Selenium look after that complexity.

Comment: @ShubhamJain What if I only wanted the attribute names without the values? The JS you provided returns both the names and the values..

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way in Selenium WebDriver to access any attribute whose full name you don't know. You can't even enumerate over all attributes of a `WebElement`.

It doesn't look like the jsonwire protocol supports this concept. The GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE command takes a list of attribute names, not a list of attribute name patterns.

It is probable that you could query via a `JavascriptExecutor` and either XPath or CSS query to find all the attribute names for your element, then use that to loop over `getAttribute`. But if you're going to do that, you can just construct your XPath or CSS query to give you the values directly, and leave the `WebElement` out of it completely.

Answer (score 1):

This concept works very well. Try this!

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("button"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Object elementAttributes = executor.executeScript("var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;",element);

System.out.println(elementAttributes.toString());
```