# Get list of HTML attributes given HTML element id

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm not really epxerienced witn XPath and I need to achieve the following:

Let's assume I'm given html tag id and I need to receive every attribute, except for id, for the html element with a given id e.g.:

As an input I'm given `id="test",`

As an ouput I need to get something like:

```
"Key" = "some-randmom-attribute"= 
"Value"="value-of-random-attribute";

"Key" = "some-randmom-attribute2"= 
"Value"="value-of-random-attribute2";
```

What I need is:

The query that would allow to get all attribute of html tag with given id,

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java with a Selenium Xpath selector:

`WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='someID']"));`

And then follow the solution created here:

[Selenium webdriver get all the data attributes of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416796/selenium-webdriver-get-all-the-data-attributes-of-an-element)